# Trying to detect if any checked values contains a specific string

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to grab the values of all checked input options from a series of checkboxes and find if any of the checked values matches a specific string:

```js
function admissible() {
  var b = 4;
  var answer = '';
  var elementsList = document.querySelectorAll("#question5" + " input:checked");

  //get the selected checkbox values for the missing elements
  if (elementsList.length >= 0) { //Code works only if some checkbox is checked
    if ((elementsList.indexOf("photo") > -1) || (elementsList.indexOf("name") > -1)) { //yes
      answer = 'yes';
    } else {
      answer = 'no';
    }
  } else {
    //display error: you must select a value
  }
  console.log(answer);
}
```

```html
<div class="questionholder" id="question5">
  <div>
    <h5>Select all elements</h5>
    <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="elementName" name="element" value="name"><label for="elementName"><p class="radioChoice">Name</p></label>
    <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="elementPhoto" name="element" value="photo"><label for="elementPhoto"><p class="radioChoice">Photo</p></label>
    <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="elementSignature" name="element" value="signature"><label for="elementSignature"><p class="radioChoice">Signature</p></label>
  </div>
  <div class="holdButtons">
    <a class="text2button" onclick="admissible()">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

elementsList doesn't seem to be storing the values of the checked boxes. How do I resolve this?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7esm36dr/)

Comment: It's `.indexOf()` not `.indexOF()`

Comment: That is a typo `indexOF()` suppose to be `indexOf()`.

Comment: fixed thet ypo but it still own't store the values

Comment: Try this `console.log(elementsList);`. What is the result?

Comment: it says elementsList.indexOf is not a function

Comment: @Sweepster check answer updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were multiple errors in this code. I also changed a bit to make it simpler.

1. You have to use [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) not `.indexOF()`. Small typos like those can throw your whole code off.
2. For `document.querySelectorAll`, you only need `input:checked`. `#question5` is completely unecessary (since none of the values have an id of `question5`).
3. `.querySelectorAll` returns a [NodeList](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodelist.asp) which is more like an object than an array. Therefore, `.indexOf()` does not work on it. You must use a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) loop or a [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) like I did in the below snippet.
4. I set the default value of `answer` to `"no"`, and if it finds photo or name, it will set the value to `"yes"` (which is easier better than having an `if else` statement for this).

The snippet below works for you.

```js
function admissible() {
  var b = 4;
  var answer = 'no';
  var elementsList = document.querySelectorAll("input:checked");

  //get the selected checkbox values for the missing elements
  if (elementsList.length >= 0) { //Code works only if some checkbox is checked

    elementsList.forEach(e => {
      if (e.value == "photo" || e.value == "name") {
        answer = "yes";
      }
    });

  } else {
    //display error: you must select a value
  }
  console.log(answer);
}
```

```html
<div class="questionholder" id="question5">
  <div>
    <h5>Select all elements</h5>
    <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="elementName" name="element" value="name"><label for="elementName"><p class="radioChoice">Name</p></label>
    <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="elementPhoto" name="element" value="photo"><label for="elementPhoto"><p class="radioChoice">Photo</p></label>
    <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="elementSignature" name="element" value="signature"><label for="elementSignature"><p class="radioChoice">Signature</p></label>
  </div>
  <div class="holdButtons">
    <a class="text2button" onclick="admissible()">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: fixed the typo, but the code isn't executing... it's not storing any of the selected checkbox values

Comment: I'm working on it. The problem is `elementsList` is not an array, but an object. So indexof won't work on it anyways. I'm working on a solution atm

Comment: @Sweepster updated my answer above to work for you.

Comment: FYI: [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) is available for [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) and does work on [most/all modern browsers, but is not compatible with IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility).

Comment: @Makyen thanks I didn't know that. I updated my answer with that. forEach loops are much easier than for loops

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of errors in your posted code. The code in the example below fixes them. The comments explain how it is solved.

### **Small summary:**

**Query selector**

```
"#question5" + " input:checked"
```

The queryselector above looks wrong. It will work, but you can combine it into one string.

```
"#question5 > div:first-child > input:checked"
```

This query selector will make a safer selection. It selects through `document.querySelectorAll` all elements of type input that are checked within the first div child element of the element with id `question5`.

**Iterating over a node list**

Since `document.querySelectorAll` returns a [`nodelist`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (array like) which is not actually an array. In your code you used `length` check to `<= 0`. This will always execute the if. Drop the `=`. Now the if only fires when the `nodelist` has at least one entry.

Then we cast the `nodeList` to an array using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and loop over it with [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). Which iterates over every element and if one condition matches it will return true.

We use [`String.prototype.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) instead of `String.prototype.indexOf` since we can use a regexp to look for the value `name|photo` in one go. The `|` (pipe) tells the code to either look for `name` or `photo`. If the result is not `-1` we found the value.

**Working example**

```js
function admissible(method) {
  var b = 4;
  var answer = '';
  var elementsList = document.querySelectorAll("#question5 > div:first-child > input:checked"); //fixed the query selector

  //get the selected checkbox values for the missing elements
  if (elementsList.length > 0) { //Code works only if some checkbox is checked
    //cast the node list to array and use array.some to iterate over entries. If one value is found answerFilter will be true.  

    if (method == "some") {
      var answerFilter = Array.from(elementsList).some(function(element) {
        return element.value.search(/name|photo/i) != -1; //check with regexp if value contains photo or name
      });
    }
    else
    {
    
      //map returns an array and lets us return a value we want.
      var answerFilter = Array.from(elementsList).map(function(element) {
        return element.value;
      });
      //now use indexOf like in the original code
      if (answerFilter.indexOf("name") > -1 || answerFilter.indexOf("photo") > -1)
      {
        answerFilter = true;
      }
      else
      {
        answerFilter = false;
      }
    }
    answerFilter ? answer = "yes" : answer = "no"; //use shorthand if/else

  } else {
    //display error: you must select a value
  }
  console.log(answer);
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

div.questionholder>div:first-child {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20px auto;
  width: 100%;
}

h5 {
  grid-area: 1 2;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

label {
  grid-column: 2;
}

label>p {
  display: inline;
}

input {
  grid-column: 1;
}

div.holdButtons {
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

div.holdButtons>a {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

div.holdButtons>a:hover {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

```html
<div class="questionholder" id="question5">
  <div>
    <h5>Select all elements</h5>
    <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="elementName" name="element" value="name"><label for="elementName"><p class="radioChoice">Name</p></label>
    <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="elementPhoto" name="element" value="photo"><label for="elementPhoto"><p class="radioChoice">Photo</p></label>
    <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="elementSignature" name="element" value="signature"><label for="elementSignature"><p class="radioChoice">Signature</p></label>
  </div>
  <div class="holdButtons">
    <a class="text2button" onclick="admissible('some')">Next <i>(Array.some)</i></a>
    <a class="text2button" onclick="admissible('map')">Next <i>(Array.map)</i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function admissible() {
    var b = 4;
    var answer = '';
    var elementsList = document.querySelectorAll("#question5"+" input:checked");

 //get the selected checkbox values for the missing elements
    if (elementsList.length >= 0) { //Code works only if some checkbox is checked
    elementsList.forEach(function(e,q,t){
    if ((e.id.indexOf("photo") > -1) || (e.id.indexOf("name") > -1)) { //yes
    answer = 'yes';
           } 
           else {
        answer = 'no';
      }
  });} else {
    //display error: you must select a value
    }
   
    console.log(answer);
}
</script>

<div class="questionholder" id="question5">
   <div>
    <h5>Select all elements</h5>
    <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="elementName" name="element" value="name"><label for="elementName"><p class="radioChoice">Name</p></label>
    <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="elementPhoto" name="element" value="photo"><label for="elementPhoto"><p class="radioChoice">Photo</p></label>
    <input class="input5" type="checkbox" id="elementSignature" name="element" value="signature"><label for="elementSignature"><p class="radioChoice">Signature</p></label> 
   </div>
   <div class="holdButtons"> 
         <a class="text2button" onclick="admissible()">Next</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

you got the complete list of the checkboxes you need to iterate through it to find if any of the checkboxes you are looking for is selected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function admissible() {
    var b = 4;
    var answer = '';
    var elementsList = document.querySelectorAll("#question5"+" input:checked");

    //get the selected checkbox values for the missing elements
    if (elementsList.length >= 0) { //Code works only if some checkbox is checked
    elementsList.forEach(function(e,q,t){
    if ((e.id.indexOf("photo") > -1) || (e.id.indexOf("name") > -1)) { //yes
                answer = 'yes';
           } 
           else {
        answer = 'no';
      }
        });} else {
    //display error: you must select a value
    }

    console.log(answer);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is a more generous way to check if an input is checked and retrieve its value. Is more of pseudo code but you can continue from here:

```
var inputList = document.querySelectorAll(".input5");

for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
    if (inputList[i].checked) {
        if (/^(photo|name)$/.test(inputList[i].value)) {
            // your code here
        }
    }
}
```